# Angular JS - display select option based on boolean value of dropdown

Tags: angularjs

Can we display alias name in the select options of dropdown using Angular JS

Issue :

Trying change Boolean value true to Ascending and false to Descending in the display of dropdown options and also trying to retain boolean value on selection of alias name - Ascending or Descending

HTML:

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
Trying to show dropdown options Ascending or Descending instead of true or false<br><br>
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x.ascending for x in names">
</select><br><br>
{{selectedName}}
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [{"name":"xxxx","ascending":true},{"name":"yyyy","ascending":false}];
});
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ZBMLep

Comment: No , I want to see Ascending and Descending instead of true or false

Comment: I am trying to see if there is any way ,can we alias boolean values to Ascending and Descending and at the same time want to use same boolean values without modifying object and using another temp object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to show **Ascending/Descending** instead of **true/false** then you can just add one ternary condition like below.

```
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="(x.ascending  ? 'Ascending' : 'Descending') for x in names track by x.ascending"></select>
```

Comment: that will show xxxx and yyyy , instead of Ascending and Descending..I want to the dropdown options to be "Ascending" and "Descending"

Comment: I have updated my code , please try with this.I hope it will work for you

Comment: modifying object and adding extra alias parameter may not be the solution

Comment: Code-only "try this" answers are the worst.  Please explain what you are doing and how it solves the problem.